SED command getting unterminated substitute pattern
I have been using this sed command for 21 months as part of a website backend build command, and it randomly started not working after I updated my computer last time (macOS 15.0.1). The purpose of this sed is to remove comments from SQL files if that helps.
This command still works on the sed tester by gnu (https://sed.js.org/)
$ sed -i 's/--.*//g' sr-api/*.sql;
sed: 1: "sr-api/36ee6939dda495a3 ...": unterminated substitute pattern

Here is the file that it fails on:
INSERT INTO stagingBuilders SET ?;

Which ironically does not contain any comments.

you're on OSX?  It provides a mostly BSD derived command line userspace.  In GNU sed, a suffix to -i is optional.  But in BSD sed, a suffix is mandatory with -i.  Use -i ''; an empty suffix will change the file in place without a backup, like you expect.
$ sed -i '' 's/--.*//' sr-api/*.sql;


That's interesting that it was working for the past 21 months without that. It might be because I reverted to bash from zsh, maybe the new sequoia update last week changed something behind the scenes. Anyway, thank you for solving this head-scratcher!

@Daniel It's not about bash vs zsh, it's about GNU sed vs BSD sed. You probably had installed GNU sed previously but now either you don't have it installed or it's in your PATH after BSD sed. FYI if you go to some other platform with neither BSD nor GNU sed then -i isn't going to work at all.

nitpick - you don't need g at the end of a sed command that replaces anything ending in .* as that substitution can only happen once per line.
